# Problem to add View dynamically in Linearlayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I want to add multiple View in a `LinearLayout`. Here is the code I am using for add adding multiple view to the `LinearLayout`.

**Java code:**

```
LinearLayout seriesMainListItemView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SeriesMainListItemView);
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                for (int i=0; i<scheduleArr.length; i++) {

                      View inflatedView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scheduleitem, null);
                      TextView inflatertext1 = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                      TextView inflatertext2 = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                      inflatertext1.setText(scheduleArr[i][0]);
                      inflatertext2.setText(scheduleArr[i][1]);
                      Log.i("data",i + " " + scheduleArr[i][0] + "/" + scheduleArr[i][1]);
                      seriesMainListItemView.addView(inflatedView);
                }
```

Here is the View xml I want to add multiple times.

Here is the LinearLayout where I want to add it.

```
<TableLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="1dip"
                android:paddingRight="1dip" >
                 <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <ImageView
                       android:id="@+id/imgSeriesMainScheduleImg"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:background="@drawable/scheduleheader"/> 
                    <LinearLayout  
                        android:id="@+id/SeriesMainListItemView"                                    
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    </LinearLayout>                                                                                              
                </TableRow>
..............
</TableLayout>
```

But only single view is adding in the LinearLayout, although length of the array is 3. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: have you set the orientation of the the LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have add the orientation of LinearLayout as Vertical. And it become perfect. Thank you Sujit for your hints.

Comment: This solved my problem! I was trying to make a custom android component and forgot to set the orientation on my new class that extends LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Use the version of `addView()` that takes a `LayoutParams` object, supply an appropriate `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried with " seriesMainListItemView.addView(inflatedView,i,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));" also, no change in result

Comment: @dalandroid: Use Hierarchy View to see if the widgets are being added. If they are not, determine why your code is not being called or something. If they are, Hierarchy View should indicate why they are not visible.